# Am I doing bad if I program a site similar to stack overflow but for spanish speakers?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, non-english-speakers

Many of my programming fellows are fluent in reading and understanding English texts but they have problems when try to write a question or explain something. I'm having the idea of program a site similar to stackoverflow but oriented to Spanish speakers. I personally think the mechanism stack overflow uses to encourage good answers to programming question rocks. Am I evil? Am I doing bad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I absolutely don't think this would be evil in any way. In fact, Jeff's blog post from [yesterday](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/), suggests to me he would encourage this, to the point of maybe even directing Spanish speaking people that direction if the question came up. As has been mentioned, stackexchange could be an option for you. However, I know the programmer in me would much rather write my own than purchase one. Additionally, depending on how you do your development, and support it while the site gets started, it may be cheaper for you. Regardless of how it's done, I think this would be a valuable service to provide and definitely not evil or bad in any way.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need for this anymore.  [Tim Post has shared](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12731/any-update-about-this-site) that work will begin on August 1, 2015 for the Spanish StackOverflow community! The expected launch date will be the last week of October/first week of November 2015.

We will now have a community where Spanish speaking developers can ask and answer questions without having to worry about communication losses by not having correct English translations.  I hope to see you there!

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, you should really wait for [StackExchange](https://stackexchange.com/) to come out and make a Spanish programming site based off that. Not only is it easier (you save on development time and cost) but it's completely evil-free.

Comment: But not completely free @Kyle... someone will have to stump up for the monthly cost.

Comment: True, it's not free, but it *is* **evil**-free. ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure how independently developing a stackoverflow-alike site that doesn't directly compete with stackoverflow is evil. Because that might be a market that StackExchange eventually wants to sell into and they might get beat to the punch? Besides, maybe victor doesn't have a profit motive and is going to have some fun developing the site to boot. Sometimes the journey is the reason for the trip...

Comment: Do users even have access to the source? I fear that StackExchange won't allow things like language localization.

Answer (score 0):

If you read Jeffs posts on this topic, this is exactly what he wants you to do so go for it. Or have a look at [stackexchange](http://www.stackexchange.com/) where you can use the framework already written to support you on this... not sure who'd pay for it though...